# Как избавиться от параллельных иерархий наследования?

Tags: java, ооп, архитектура

Я решаю задачу о нахождении лидера ([leader election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_election))
Это чисто алгоритмическая задача, у которой есть 2 формы: однонаправленное кольцо и двунаправленное. Для представления данных я создал свой собственный класс для списка, закрученного в кольцо. То есть у меня два алгоритма, по одному для каждой формы задачи.

```
public abstract class MyAbstractRoundList {

    protected int size;
    protected Agent[] arr = new Agent[1];
    protected int index = 0;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public void add(Agent agent) {
        if (size >= arr.length) {
            Agent[] temp = arr;
            arr = new Agent[temp.length * 2];
            System.arraycopy(temp, 0, arr, 0, temp.length);
        }
        arr[size++] = agent;
    }
// и дальше еще много методов
```

Далее я создаю наследников этого класса для однонаправленного режима и для двунаправленного. Реализации в них конечно различаются. Далее, у меня есть класс:

```
public class LeaderElection {

public static void solve(MyAbstractList list, int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        list.initiateStartState();
    } else {
        list.setMessages();
    }
}
```

}

В нем у меня решение для однонаправленного режима. И есть похожий класс с решением для двунаправленного, но реализации конечно тоже различаются. Что бы не прописывать в клиентском коде

```
    if(isOneDirectMode()){
        LeaderElection.solve();
    {
    if(isBiDirectMode()){
        BiLeaderElection.solve();
    }
```

Я мог бы так же создать абстрактный класс для решения и его наследников и пользоваться полиморфизмом (так я и делаю для списков). Но вот тут и возникает проблема: у меня получаются параллельные иерархии наследования. Если появится новый режим я должен буду добавить новый класс подкласс `MyAbstractRoundList` и новый подкласс решения. Можно как то избавиться от этого? Я вижу только один способ: Можно было бы сделать в MyAbstractRoundList абстрактный метод solve() и реализовывать его в подклассах каждого режима так как это требуется для конкретного режима. Но это плохо, потому что тогда у меня подклассы `MyAbstractRoundList` будут не только хранить данные, но и решать задачу. То есть выполнять 2 функции.

Comment: А чем плоха параллельная иерархия?

Comment: @VladD, ваш вопрос поставил меня в тупик) даже не знаю, но всегда считал что это плохо. Может потому что можно их не согласовать?

Comment: Смотрите. Понятно, что лишнюю функциональность не нужно включать в основную иерархию, так что код «сбоку» необходим. Проблема по сути в диспетчеризации: когда вы вызываете виртуальный метод, имея ссылку на базовый класс, у вас вызывается правильный метод производного класса. А когда у вас вместо этого параллельная иерархия, диспетчеризировать вызов по типу из основной иерархии язык не умеет.

Comment: Поэтому ставить в соответствие основному типу тип из дополнительной иерархии придётся вручную. (Да, это болезненный момент, его невозможно автоматизировать.) Но это является по сути хорошим компромиссом к тому, чтобы не паковать всю функциональность вместе в базовую иерархию. [Ну и в конкретно вашем случае параллельная иерархия может быть и не нужна, но это не так уж и важно.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Они не параллельны. Изменения в одной иерархии никак не влекут за собой изменения в другой иерархии.

> Если появится новый режим я должен буду добавить новый класс подкласс
>   MyAbstractRoundList и новый подкласс решения. Можно как то избавиться
>   от этого? Я вижу только один способ: Можно было бы сделать в
>   MyAbstractRoundList абстрактный метод solve() и реализовывать его в
>   подклассах каждого режима так как это требуется для конкретного
>   режима.

Решение задачи - это **поведение**. Поведение лучше описывать интерфейсами.

```
public interface Solver {
    void solve(MyAbstractList list, int i);
}
...
public class LeaderElection implements Solver {

...
public class BiLeaderElection implements Solver {

...
public class MultiTreadingLeaderElection implements Solver {
```

У вас отдельная иерархия наследования классов, отвечающих за хранение данных, и отдельная иерархия классов, отвечающих за решения. Это нормально. Если появится новый вид хранения (новый тип списка), вы добавите новый класс-наследник `MyAbstractRoundList`. Это никак не связано с решениями, новый класс может использоваться и существующими решениями. Если потребуется добавить новый способ решения, вы добавите новый класс, реализующий интерфейс `Solver`, и это не обязательно должно отразиться на иерархии классов для хранения.

При таком подходе у вас всегда будет работать код `solver.solve(abstractList, i);`, если в переменную `solver` положить объект любого класса, реализующего интерфейс `Solver`, а в переменную `abstractList` - любой объект класса-наследника `MyAbstractRoundList`, и самое главное - этот код не придется менять при добавлении новых классов, как и должно быть с точки зрения ООП.

---

**UPD.** Есть данные, есть поведение. В рамках класса **поля** описывают данные, **методы** - поведение. Например, я руковожу бригадой роботов. Одни из них могут **строить**, другие - **переносить**, третьи - **разрушать**, четвертые - **поливать**. Робот-строитель, например, может принести себе стройматериал, но только в небольшом количестве, таким образом, он может и строить, и носить. А робот-носитель - только носить. И если вдруг поступает задача срочно разгрузить вагон стройматериалов, то мне надо собрать всех роботов, умеющих носить. И мне плевать, что это за роботы. Хоть робот-поливалка. Если может носить - пусть идет носить. Я просто выберу роботов с **нужным мне поведением**, и буду уверен, что они смогут сделать то, что мне надо.

```
public interface Carrier {
    void carry(); //нести
}

public interface Builder {
    void build(); //построить
}

public interface Destroer {
    void destroy(); //сломать
}

public class RobotBuilder extends Robot implements Builder, Carrier {
    public void carry() {

    }

    public void build() {

    }
}

public class RobotDestroer extends Robot implements Destroer {
    public void destroy() {

    }
}

public class RobotCarrier extends Robot implements Carrier {
    public void carry() {

    }
}
```

Comment: а что такое поведение, подскажите пожалуйста? Это какой то паттерн?

Comment: Добавил объяснение. Надеюсь, понятно.